# unity new input system support for mice with more than 5 buttons

Tags: unity-game-engine

The old input system had support for mice with up to 7 buttons; KeyCode went from Mouse0 to Mouse6. The new input system, however, has

leftButton
rightButton
middleButton
forwardButton
backButton
Only 5 buttons. Can we get support for many-buttoned mice like [this one](https://www.corsair.com/us/en/Categories/Products/Gaming-Mice/MMO-Role-Play-Mice/scimitar-pro-config/p/CH-9304011-NA)?

Comment: good question! Might have to go by `Usages`?

Comment: unity new input system can support for the 7+ side mouse buttons ?

Comment: I don't think so .. probably would need to [implement a custom device](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/HowDoI.html#create-my-own-custom-devices) for it then

Comment: After read that doc, I don't know how to implement a custom device with mouse 7+ side button..Can you show me some example, please

Comment: An easy way to check support is to go to the section where you bind and click the listen button.  While it is listening for inputs, press the mouse button(s) in question.  The binding name will be displayed and you can determine if it is supported or not.

Comment: I try it, but it juest display 2 sdie mouse buttons, other 4 buttons not display. I have to try implement a custom device.

Comment: I use mouse is logitech G502 HERO.